# Was Mount Erebor called "The Lonely Mountain" because it was the singular feature in the area, or for some other reason?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

Was Mount Erebor called "The Lonely Mountain" because it was the singular feature in the area, or for some other reason?

[image: Map]

The map to *The Lonely Mountain*.

Comment: Are you referring to the Erebor in Middle Earth or the one on Titan?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This map](http://www.monkeyinthecage.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Map-of-Middle-earth.jpg) at http://www.monkeyinthecage.com/2012/11/05/top-five-reasons-to-be-excited-about-the-hobbit/ would seem to indicate that it is indeed by itself.

[image]

From memory of the book, it seems likely that there are low-lying hills around it, but it is described as a single dominating peak over the landscape.

Comment: man, those maps are so beautiful... inspired many lonely but exciting hours of making useless maps of imaginary realms as a teenager.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

As explained by Tolkien scholars Wayne Hammond and Christina Scull, the mountain is named such because it is an isolated peak.

> *Erebor*, the Lonely Mountain, is an isolated peak to the east of the northernmost parts of Mirkwood; its Sindarin name contains the element *er* ‘one, alone’ (as in *Eriador*).
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion* - "Prologue"</sub>

The Sindarin name *Erebor* is derived from the word *er*, "one, alone",  as indicated by Christopher Tolkien in his linguistic appendix to The Silmarillion.

> *er* 'one, alone', in *Amon Ereb* (cf. *Erebor*, the Lonely Mountain), *Erchamion*, *Eressëa*, *Eru*.
> <sub>*The Silmarillion* - "Elements in Quenya and Sindarin Names"</sub>

The mountain itself is an isolated peak, seperated from nearby hills in the Northeast by "tumbled" or "broken" lands.

> Suddenly the cliff fell away. The shores sank. The trees ended. Then Bilbo saw a sight: The lands opened wide about him, filled with the waters of the river which broke up and wandered in a hundred winding courses, or halted in marshes and pools dotted with isles on every side: but still a strong water flowed on steadily through the midst. **And far away, its dark head in a torn cloud, there loomed the Mountain! Its nearest neighbours to the North-East and the tumbled land that joined it to them could not be seen. All alone it rose and looked across the marshes to the forest.** The Lonely Mountain! Bilbo had come far and through many adventures to see it, and now he did not like the look of it in the least.
> <sub>*The Hobbit* - Chapter 10 "A Warm Welcome"</sub>

> Not even the ravens knew of [the goblins] coming until they came out in **the broken lands which divided the Lonely Mountain from the hills behind.** How much Gandalf knew cannot be said, but it is plain that he had not expected this sudden assault.
> <sub>*The Hobbit* - Chapter 17 "The Clouds Burst"</sub>

This geography can also be seen in all nineteen of Tolkien's maps and illustrations of the Lonely Mountain and its surrounding areas, which are reproduced in *The Art of The Hobbit*, figures 24-29, 74-77,80-85, and 87-89.

> [image: I think these images]
> [image: are already sufficiently]
> [image: described elsewhere in]
> [image: this answer. As such,]
> [image: any alt text you add]
> [image: here would be redundant.]
> <sub>*The Art of The Hobbit* - figures 24, 26, 75, 83, 87, 89</sub>
> <sub>[24. Early manuscript for Chapter 1, with sketch of *Thor's Map*](https://tai.tolkienists.org/tai/133/) (Marquette MS. Tolkien MSs-1/1/1)</sub>
> <sub>[26. Sketch for *Thor's Map*](https://tai.tolkienists.org/tai/320/) (Bodleian MS. Tolkien Drawings 22v)</sub>
> <sub>[75. Smaug flies around the lonely mountain](https://tai.tolkienists.org/tai/111/) (Bodleian MS. Tolkien Drawings 89, fol. 24r)</sub>
> <sub>[83. Map of the Lonely Mountain and its surrounding Lands](https://tai.tolkienists.org/tai/332/) (Bodleian MS. Tolkien Drawings 89, fol. 51r)</sub>
> <sub>[87. *The Lonely Mountain* and map of the Long Lake](https://tai.tolkienists.org/tai/236/) (Bodleian MS. Tolkien Drawings 89, fol. 26r)</sub>
> <sub>[89. *Wilderland*, final art](https://tai.tolkienists.org/tai/14/) (Bodleian MS. Tolkien Drawings 35r)</sub>

Karen Wynn Fonstad speculates that this would be an indication of continental glaciation, though it's unclear if Tolkien had any such thought in mind.

> The extensive bogs and marshes at the end of both forest roads, the Long Marshes along the Forest River, the "tumbled land" between Lonely Mountain and its nearest neighbors to the northeast, and most especially the description of Long Lake, all point toward effects of continental glaciation.
> <sub>*The Atlas of Middle-earth* - "Wilderland"</sub>